# Resigning as a mod, effective immediately

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm resigning as a pro-tem moderator on Writing, effective immediately.

Stack Exchange is a company that relies on volunteer labor from users and moderators. I've valued my connections with Stack Exchange over the years, both as pro-tem moderator of Bicycles and later here on Writing. I've enjoyed being a user on cooking, sci-fi, and dabbled in the music site. The network has enriched my life, and I've felt that Stack Exchange sites have been a good use of my energy.

Recently, Monica Cellio was fired as a mod across the network, and from what I can see, no warning or thought given to the effects this would have.

The timing of this is also unfortunate: Minutes before the Jewish Shabbat, when Monica would no longer be online, and immediately before the Rosh Hashana/Yom Kippur high holiday season. I suspect this timing is simply unfortunate and not an intentional slight, but if Stack Exchange is serious about tolerance and inclusivity, this isn't the way to go about it.

We may never know all the details of the situation completely, but I trust Monica and feel that [her version of events](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/647) ([alternate link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190930211656/https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel)) is as correct as she could make it. I also feel that Stack Exchange as a company has been becoming more and more of a black box.

While I don't believe this resignation will change anything, I no longer want to volunteer my time for a company that will treat a long-standing moderator in this way. I sincerely hope that the company will rethink its decision and come to a more nuanced decision, but at the moment this is not happening, despite [extensive community discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/334012#334012).

This has been an amazing community and it's been an honor to work here.

Comment: You are a good and honorable person and you've been a great mod.

Comment: Hi, I'm Aerovistae. Haven't participated in this particular SE site in a few years now but used to love it when I first stumbled onto this network. Sorry to see you go Neil, I always remember you doing a great job.

Comment: I just wanted to add my voice to this as well. It's been some time since I was a mod here, and it took me a few weeks to find out about all this -- but holy heck. Kudos to Monica. Shock and dismay at SE.

Answer (score 48):

You were already a moderator when I was appointed in 2013, and you helped me and future moderators get settled.  You have contributed a *lot* to this site over many years.  Thank you for all your service.  It was a pleasure to work with you.

Comment: Monica, you have always been a model of graciousness, tolerance, and patience, and I am terribly sorry you have been treated so badly.